# On event start calling function periodically

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I have this problem:**

I have real time form validation, but the inputs have autocomplete on, so when you choose a value from it, it wont trigger eny event and I cant start validating the new value.

**Here is some solution which I have figured**

I was thinking when input triggers onfocus event, i can start periodically (for example every one second) calling some validating functions on input, whether the value changes or not.

And on blur event I want to stop calling the function.

But I cant figure it out how to start call the function periodically...

What I have so far:

```
$('input[name="'+input_name+'"]').focus(function(){

            checkInput(input_name);

});

function checkInput(input_name){

    setInterval(doneTyping(input_name),700);
    console.log(1);
}
```

But this only happens once, how could I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` needs an anonymous function

```
myInterval = setInterval(function(){doneTyping(input_name);},700);

//To clear
clearTimeout(myInterval);
```

Comment: Though this will work, note that setInterval does not necessarily need an anonymous function. Even named functions (or even a string of code) will do.

Comment: @techfoobar Ah ok, so what's the issue then?

Comment: The issue is that setInterval needs a function, and he is not passing a function but the value that calling doneTyping(input_name) returns

Comment: I forget the part about anonymous function in setInterval, much thx

Answer (score 1):

do it like

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(function(){ doneTyping(input_name); }, 700);
```

see [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BaSuv/1/).

Comment: Thx that worked for me too, ill be accepting as an answer post from Rob because he answers quicker.